# I get a Notice: Undefined index when I pass a variable to another page

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to pass a variable from one page to another using a URL but I get a NOTICE. I have read that NOTICE or WARNINGS can be suppressed, by I want to learn how to fix this if possible. Thanks!

```
Notice: Undefined index: status in /view_dept.php on line 139
```

this is the URL and where the query happens - (technically the page1 - where the variable comes from):

```
header('location:view_dept.php?status=success');
```

This is the "page2", where I need to pass the variable so I can echo a success message. This is the MAIN PAGE.

```
<?php
    if( $_GET['status'] == 'success'):
        echo 'SUCCESS';
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: page2 is view_dept.php?

Comment: Your code is fine. Check if there is some other problem before the line 139.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the Notice, try `isset()` to check if the index status is present

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 'success'):
    echo 'SUCCESS';
endif;
?>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a bunch.